# Django serve files from STATIC_ROOT and use AppDirectoriesFinder at same time

Tags: django

I'm trying and failing to figure out a config for serving static files that works for me under these requirements:

- I want the `collectstatic` command to work always  (when `Debug=True`, and `Debug=False`), and to collect app dir statics. This implies I need both 'django.contrib.staticfiles' in INSTALLED_APPS and 'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder' in STATICFILES_FINDERS.
- I want to serve *some* files out of STATIC_ROOT with Debug=True (Debug=False I want to serve all files out of STATIC_ROOT), that don't belong to any particular app. I just do.
- I want the dev server (./manage.py runserver) AppDirectoriesFinder lookups to work when `Debug=True`.
- As a compromise I could live with all static files out of STATIC_ROOT, but I still need `Debug=True` and `collectstatic` to work.

But I can't figure out how to do this.

- I can't add STATIC_ROOT to STATICFILES_DIRS (not allowed)
- Adding `urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)` to urls as [suggested here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/static-files/#serving-static-files-during-development) does seem to not work in `Debug=True` with the dev server because the dev server overrides it and uses static finders.

Any ideas?

Comment: `STATIC_ROOT` is where everything that is collected during `collectstatic` is put. *You shouldn't be manually putting stuff in there (it sounds like you are doing that - don't!)*. `AppDirectoriesFinder` is just used to tell `collectstatic` to look in your apps when collecting static files.

Comment: Hi @solarissmoke, I was expecting exactly that critisism... Yeah I am doing exactly that. But I want to. Why should't I?

Comment: @solarissmoke AppDirectoriesFinder is also used dynamically by the dev server to find files in Debug=True mode.

Comment: Because you cannot guarantee that what is put there will stay there. Here is the warning from [documentation itself](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/settings/#static-root): *This should be an initially empty destination directory for collecting your static files from their permanent locations into one directory for ease of deployment; **it is not a place to store your static files permanently**. You should do that in directories that will be found by staticfiles’s finders, which by default, are `'static/'` app sub-directories and any directories you include in `STATICFILES_DIRS`).*

Comment: `AppDirectoriesFinder` and every other location in `STATICFILES_DIRS` is checked dynamically during debug. It's a feature to ease development.

Comment: Thanks @solarissmoke. Read that earlier. I'm pretty sure I want to do it anyway. I know `collectstatic` is going to dump files in STATIC_ROOT. But I'm confident I can avoid collisions.

Comment: I'm just curious - can you explain *why* you want to do that? What is the reason not to put your static files somewhere else?

Comment: Because they are generated by a independent script and they are very big.